# get data from 2 tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i have 4 tables: questions, answers, users, and inquiries (relationship-table between all of them)

this my_controller

```
  def index
    question_id = params[:id].to_i
    question    = Question.find(question_id)
    @answers    = question.answers

    respond_to do |format|
      format.ext_json { render :json => @answers.to_ext_json(:class =>
Answer) }
    end
  end
```

I have grids in extjs, when I click on row, i get answers on
question that i just selected, COOL. But i need paste in this info email
of people (emails stores in users table). Now i have this:

```
| id | answer |
  1  |   lala
  2  |   lalala2
```

but i need this:

```
| id | answer |  email
  1  |   lala |  alal@sa.com
  2  |   lal2 |  asasa@was.net
```

p.s

```
users (table): id, email 
questions (table): id, text 
inquiries: question_id, user_id 
answers: inquiry_id, text
```

Model of users:

```
has_many :inquiries 
has_many :questions, :through => :inquiries 
has_many :answers, :through => :inquiries
```

question model:

```
has_many :inquiries, :dependent => :destroy 
has_many :answers, :through => :inquiries, :dependent => :destroy
```

answer model

```
  belongs_to :inquiry
  belongs_to :question
```

inquiry model

```
  belongs_to  :question
  belongs_to  :users
  has_one    :answer, :dependent => :destroy
```

Comment: what is the relation between User & Question ?????

Comment: users (table): id, email / questions (table): id, text |
inquiries: question_id, user_id . Model of users:   has_many :inquiries
  has_many :questions, :through => :inquiries
  has_many :answers,   :through => :inquiries / and question model:   has_many :inquiries, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :answers, :through => :inquiries, :dependent => :destroy

Comment: How about table Answers and link bettwen Question and Answers?

Comment: First 3 lines in controller's action `index` can be done in one: `@answers = Question.find(params[:id]).answers`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need something like this:

In Answer model

```
has_one :user, :through => :inquiries
```

Comment: and in controller i should write something?

Comment: In Json it would look like 
render :json => @answers.to_json(:include => {:user => {:only => :email}})